# find list of classes and custom annotations

Tags: scala, inheritance

How can one or all of the following be done.
Get all classes during runtime in Scala

1. in a package
2. that extend a particular trait
3. with a custom annotation

Comment: Reflection. And this probably means you have an error in your design.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Actually not with standard reflection.

Comment: standard reflection doesn't work with scala. it's not very straight fwd.  I've tried many different combos.

Comment: @forkit Standard reflection does work with Scala. Moreover such working standard reflections are Java reflection (runtime), Scala reflection (compile-time and runtime). Just finding all classes in a package is not a standard reflection task and is not easy because of JVM nature. Did you try libraries (Reflections, ClassGraph...)?

Answer (score 0):

Use proper IDE.

For example, in Intellij IDEA to achieve

- (1) you can type package and then see suggestions.
- (2) you can use `Ctrl+H`.

I think there is a way to do exactly what you want.

Or you can use compiler's meta format to analyze it by yourself.

Comment: If you create a class dynamically at runtime will IDE show it?

Comment: I'm looking to do this in runtime via code, not in the IDE.